# Get back to default login shell after running /bin/bash

Tags: bash, permissions, tcpdump

When logging in the prompt is different than it is after executing /bin/bash

```
-bash-4.2$ exec bash
bash-4.2$
```

How do I get the `-` back in front of the bash. There are certain commands like tcp dump that only work in the orignal

```
-bash-4.2$ tcpdump -i port1 -w /home/user/$HOSTNAME-port1.pcap -c10000 -G300
tcpdump: WARNING: port1: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: listening on port1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
-bash-4.2$ exec bash
bash-4.2$ tcpdump -i port1 -w /home/user/$HOSTNAME-port1.pcap -c10000 -G300
tcpdump: port1: You don't have permission to capture on that device
(socket: Operation not permitted)
```

Update for @ctrl-alt-delor

```
-bash-4.2$ groups
nuage
-bash-4.2$ exec bash
bash-4.2$ groups
nuage
```

update for @Mikel

```
bash-4.2$ exec bash -l
bash-4.2$
```

Update for @Mark Plotnick

```
-bash-4.2$ type tcpdump
tcpdump is aliased to 'sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump'
-bash-4.2$ exec bash
bash-4.2$ type tcpdump
tcpdump is /usr/sbin/tcpdump
[root@host nuage]# cat /etc/sudoers | grep nuage
[root@host nuage]# exit
bash-4.2$ group
bash-4.2$ groups
nuage
bash-4.2$ whoami
nuage
```

Comment: Can you run `groups` before and after. Put the result in the question.

Comment: The `-` just means it's a login shell.  Try `exec bash -l`.  I wonder if this is somehow related to SELinux or some other role-based access control system.  But why are you doing `exec bash` in the first place?

Comment: @Mikel Updated in original, this was the simplest form of the problem, the reason I need to find out how to run things as the original shell is because I must run a script and #!/bin/bash has different permissions than what was used to create the definition for the script.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `type tcpdump` before and after?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Updated in main. How is it possible that I can run a command with sudo, and require no password, when there is also no mention of this user in the sudoers file...

Comment: Try `exec -a -bash bash` ; I think that ought to set things up so that your shell init files are read in by the new bash and thus you'll see all your aliases.

Comment: What does that do? Id like to understand what is actually wrong here so I don't need to ask this again. Also if you want you can post your solution as a full answer and I can mark it as accepted (It does work by the way)

Comment: The underlying problem is that aliases aren't automatically passed from one shell to a new shell ; when you start a new shell, they're read in from one or more of your shell init  files. One way to ensure this is to always start bash as `-bash`, and that's what the `-a` option to `exec` lets you do. But there's probably a better solution to your problem, such as putting your aliases in the file  `.bashrc` in your home directory.  Can you try that?

Comment: Due to the nature of where this script will be run it needs to be entirely self contained without having to modify the machine it is run on. But if I run into this issue on a personal machine then I will certainly try that

Comment: As it is a script, you should not load the users aliases (this is why it behaves differently), so add the appropriate aliases to the script.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick If you write up mentioning underlying problem, and fix by added just the alias you need, and why it does not run users config. Then I will give it my +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Problem :*** After executing `exec bash` the aliases present in the default login prompt are lost causing some commands to not work as expected, such as tcpdump in the following example

```
-bash-4.2$ tcpdump -i port1 -w /home/user/$HOSTNAME-port1.pcap -c10000 -G300
tcpdump: WARNING: port1: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: listening on port1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
-bash-4.2$ exec bash
bash-4.2$ tcpdump -i port1 -w /home/user/$HOSTNAME-port1.pcap -c10000 -G300
tcpdump: port1: You don't have permission to capture on that device
(socket: Operation not permitted)
```

***The Fix :*** You can do what I did and figure out how the aliases change between the different prompts

```
-bash-4.2$ type tcpdump
tcpdump is aliased to 'sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump'
-bash-4.2$ exec bash
bash-4.2$ type tcpdump
tcpdump is /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

and then change the script to use those `sudo tcpdump` instead of plain `tcpdump`.

Or alternatively you can restore all the aliases present in the original prompt by running `exec -a -bash bash` (which is apaprently not recommended, see @ctrl-alt-delor's comment)